# Equivalence Relations of pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

My question is:

Let $H$ and $J$ be the Equivalence relations in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$. that is:

$$H = \bigg{\{}[(a,b),(c,d)]: b-a = d-c\bigg{\}}$$
$$J = \bigg{\{}[(a,b),(c,d)]: a+b = c+d\bigg{\}}$$
$(a,b,c,d \in  \mathbb  R)$

Prove that $H \circ J$ = $J \circ H$ and conclude that 
$H \circ J$ is an equivalence relation. 
And describe the equivalent class modulo $H \circ J$.

I cannot even figure out how to start this. 
Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Well, how do you define $\circ$ for relations. Start from there. - But first, complete the problem statement by specifying whch set $a,b,$ etc. are taken from.

Comment: Oh Thanks...! I'll Correct immediately.

Comment: So, what is  $\circ$?

Comment: ∘ is a notation for composite.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the usual definition of composition of equivalence relations (or binary relations, in general) applies. So 
$$H\circ J = \left\{ ((a,b),(c,d)) \in (\mathbb R^2)^2 : 
\exists (u,v) \in \mathbb R^2 \bigl( 
((a,b),(u,v)) \in H \,\&\, ((u,v),(c,d)) \in J \bigr) \right\}.$$
So let $(a,b),(c,d)$ be arbitrary elements of $\mathbb R^2$ and define
$$u=\frac{a-b+c+d}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad v=\frac{-a+b+c+d}{2}.$$
It follows that
$$v-u=\frac{2b-2a}{2}= b-a$$
and
$$u+v=\frac{2c+2d}{2}=c+d,$$
whence
$$((a,b),(u,v)) \in H \quad\text{and}\quad ((u,v),(c,d))\in J,$$
and therefore $((a,b),(c,d))\in H\circ J$.
It follows that $H\circ J = (\mathbb R^2)^2$.
Similarly, $J\circ H = (\mathbb R^2)^2$.

So $H\circ J = J \circ H$ is an equivalence relation with only one equivalence class, that is $\mathbb R^2$.